# How do American speakers use the present subjunctive in a less formal way on American-English?

Tags: american-english, british-english, subjunctive-mood, north-american-english, should

Although we don't use present subjunctive often, there are some kind of times you practically need to use it. For example, in British-English you usually use "should" in the present subjunctive clause. Let's take a look:

"The teacher demanded that the student not miss the classes anymore."

British people would usually say "The teacher demanded that the student should not miss the classes anymore." instead; otherwise, they know it would sound too formal.

But I just found how to make present subjunctive LESS FORMALLY in British-English by using "should". But I didn't find anywhere in internet a teacher explaining how we can use the present subjunctive in a less formal way the same thing we do in British-English (since people say "should" is not used in present subjunctive on American-English).

Thanks in advance for those who can help me!

Comment: Preliminary point: the construction with "should" is mandative but it's not subjunctive. The latter is a clause type headed by a plain form verb, not by "should".

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133883/discussion-on-question-by-lp0956-how-do-american-speakers-use-the-present-subjun).

Answer (score 2):

Well, I like using the subjunctive in English.

But I can tell you what I've observed in the US, where I live (I've never lived in the UK -- only visited).  Most people I come into contact say things like

"The teacher said the student can't miss any more classes."

And instead of "I'd rather that you used your inside voice," I hear, "Would you use your inside voice, please?"

If you provide more examples I guess I could be more helpful.  (Which is true -- but notice what I did there?)

Comment: OK, but define 'subjunctive'.

Comment: @BillJ - Wait, why do I have to do that?  OP gave one example.  It's really up to OP if they want more.